# Using chart.addAxis and defining a title for the horizontal line on a Line graph the title is inverted

Tags: dojox.charting

How do you define a title that will not be inverted on the horizontal axis of a line graph, using the chart.addAxis method. Currently my code is seen below. What happens is when the "X Axis" is rendered it is inverted upside down.

chart1.setTheme(dojox.charting.themes.ThreeD);

```
chart1.addAxis("x", {
  title: 'X Axis',
  range: { lower: 0, upper: 70},
  //to enable scaling of ticks
  //majorTickStep: 4,
  //minorTickStep: 2,
  //microTickStep: 1
  //to enable min and max range
  //min: 0,
  //max: 10,
  showTicks : true,
  min: 0,
       max: 10,
  fixLower: "major", 
      fixUpper: "major",
      majorTick: { stroke: "black", length: 3 },
      minorTick: { stroke: "gray", length: 3 }
});
chart1.addAxis("y", {
  title: 'Y Axis',
      vertical: true,
  scale: 2 ,
  showTicks : true,
      fixLower: "major", 
      fixUpper: "major",
      majorTick: { stroke: "black", length: 3},
      minorTick: { stroke: "gray", length: 3 },
  //htmlLabels: false
});
```

Answer (score 7):

set `titleOrientation: "away"`

See the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/charting.html#axis-title)

> **param:** titleOrientation
>   **type:** string
>   **default:** axis
>   **description:** determine the title orientation to the axis, facing to the axis by "axis", or facing away from the axis by "away".