# Title of axis is affecting when 'rotation' is used - dojo-charts

Tags: dojox.charting

I have given 'rotation:-90' to make the lables of x-axis to rotate.
But that rotation is even applied for the title of the axis also.
How can I stop that? Please anyone help me.
Below is the code I'm using..

```
          makeCharts = function() {
          var chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("simplechart", {
                      title: "Production(Quantity)",
                      titlePos: "top",
                      titleGap: 5,
                          titleFont: "normal normal normal 15pt Arial",
                      titleFontColor: "orange"
            });

            chart1.addPlot("default",{type:"ClusteredColumns", 
                                            gap: 5, 
                                            animate:{duration: 500} })
            chart1.addSeries("2008", [113.1,72.1,62.6,59.8,59.3,53.7,52.4,49.1,43.7,40.9], {fill: "#DDFEDC"});
            chart1.addSeries("2007",[113.6,65.0,59.2,56.4,62.8,53.5,47.6,44.9,41.5,39.1], {fill: "#FCDEFD"});
            chart1.addAxis("x", {
            title:'x-axis title comes here',
            includeZero: false, 
            labels:[
                {value:1, text:'one'},
                                {value:2, text:'two'},
                                {value:3, text:'three'},
                                {value:4, text:'four'},
                                {value:5, text:'five'},
                                {value:6, text:'six'},
                                {value:7, text:'seven'},
                                {value:8, text:'eight'},
                                {value:9, text:'nine'},
                                {value:10, text:'ten'}                                                     
                            ],
            rotation:-90
        }
            );
            chart1.addAxis("y", {
            vertical: true,
            includeZero: true, 
            from:0, 
            to:200,
            minorTickStep:20}
        );
    var anim4b = new dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip(chart1, 'default');
            chart1.render();

    new dojox.charting.widget.Legend({chart:chart1, horizontal: true}, "legend");
        };
    dojo.addOnLoad(makeCharts);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for this issue...
here is the code

```
var setAxisTitle=function(chart, axisname, title, fontsizept) {
    var axis = chart.axes[axisname];
    var dim = chart.dim;
    var offsets=chart.offsets;
    var ta = chart.theme.axis;
    var taFont = "font" in axis.opt ? axis.opt.font : ta.font;
    var x;
    var y;
    var label;
    var rotate=0;
    if(axis.vertical) {
       rotate=270
       label = title;
       y=dim.height/2  - offsets.b/2;
       x=0+2*fontsizept;
    } else {
       label = title;
       x=dim.width/2 + offsets.l/2;
       y=dim.height-fontsizept/2;
    }
    var m = dojox.gfx.matrix;
    var elem = axis.group.createText({x:x, y:y, text:label, align: "middle"});
    elem.setFont({family:taFont.family, size: fontsizept+"pt", weight: "bold"});
    elem.setFill('grey');
    elem.setTransform(m.rotategAt(rotate, x,y)); 
}
```

it can be called as

```
mychart.render();
setAxisTitle(mychart,"x","Title for X axis",10);
setAxisTitle(mychart,"y","Title for Y axis",10);
```

--
SuryaPavan

Answer (score 5):

I have just encountered a similar problem as you and stumbled across a slightly easier solution to the one you proposed above.

From http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/charting.html#axis-title:

> *titleOrientation* determines the title orientation to the axis, facing to the axis by
>   “axis”, or facing away from the axis by “away”.

I found that by adding `titleOrientation: "away"` to the x axis parameters this will override the existing `rotation` parameter and thus solves the problem.

FYI: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022946/using-chart-addaxis-and-defining-a-title-for-the-horizontal-line-on-a-line-graph)